# Schedule Fortnightly jobs on jenkins

Tags: cron, jenkins

I wanted to schedule fortnightly job on jenkin . It should run every other Monday . I am not able to figure out the cron expression

Comment: @AndersLindahl its a weekly cron. I am looking at fortnightly cron.  It should run every OTHER Monday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a little research, and it basically comes down to 3 answers that I can find:

**Quick answer**:  You can't.

**Complex answer 1**:  You could manually put in an entry for every other Sunday on a separate line, but this will run into problems when the year changes

```
0 0 29 4 *
0 0 13 5 *
0 0 27 5 *
0 0 10 6 *
...
```

**Complex answer 2**:  Create a cron entry that runs every Sunday, and then use something in your build steps that manually checks (toggles) to solve the "every other" part of the problem.  (If you need to do the test before the SCM step, the pre-scm-buildstep plugin might help.)

Answer (score 1):

In your project ***Configure / Build Triggers / Schedule*** section you can specify `@weekly`

That will be executed after midnight the first day of the week, based in you JVM locale.

That's the closest you will get from inside Jenkins. Otherwise you'll need to use some external cron job.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 0 * * #1,#3
```

According to [this](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/cron+expression/en-en/#Hash_.28.23.29), the hash character should allow the above expression to give you a build at midnight, every month, on the first and 3rd Mondays. This is as close as I could find to every-other-Monday.

Comment: jenkins doesnt support hash. I just dont know you do they not support normal crontab instead for writing their own implementation

Comment: Actually, apparently they have added it as of v1.460 (unless I misunderstood the changelog) http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog

Comment: the hash functionality that jenkins have introduce is about distributing execution of jobs over a period of time to minimize the sudden spike.

Comment: LOL You just pasted here what the changelog says. Thanks? Anyway, I tried it and it didn't work. Best option would be what @jwernerny said

Comment: Oh, these are nice additions. Can you please file this as a ticket to Jenkins so that we can add it?

Comment: @KohsukeKawaguchi Kohsuke, I have opened a ticket on Jenkins JENKINS-13641

Comment: Still not implemented as of April 2017 -> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13641