# Jenkins Build Periodically - Once

Tags: jenkins, cron

I am trying to schedule a Jenkins Deployment task to run **only once**. 
Why? So no one has to log in remotely to do after hours deployments (No Fun!)

So my question is: **Is there a way to specify year within jenkins' cron syntax?**

More info:
Under Build Triggers -> Build Periodically 
If I schedule a build for today(Thursday, June 10th) at 10:52 AM 
The cron syntax would be `52 10 10 6 2`

However, the next June 10th will occur in the year 2025, so technically, the build will still be scheduled for 11 years from now, unless I manually remove the schedule.

This is not a huge problem, it just doesn't make sense to me someone hasn't come up with a solution for it yet.

I am not looking for hacks, scheduled tasks, or scripting... All of that would be more work then just manually removing the schedule. I would like to keep this completely inside of jenkins

If this is truly impossible, I will consider writing a plugin for this specific use-case.

Comment: You need to schedule it ? Why don'y you just run the job manually with no cron info.
Your job will be launched only on demand... which is in fact once ! ;)

Comment: @aorfevre Well that would require me to work from home. The point of scheduling is to set it to a certain time of day(night). I only run into this problem with production deployments. It is a really bad idea to upgrade production applications during the day, while they're being used. Either way, I just found another question that was identical to mine.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314343/schedule-fortnightly-jobs-on-jenkins?rq=1 ... so perhaps I should close this one..

Comment: Correction, that question is a different scenario. I don't think this is possible, but I'm hoping someone found a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after much digging I finally found it: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Schedule+Build+Plugin

[image]

It adds ^^ the schedule build button to all projects which provides a nice UI to set a date and time, instead of dealing with that ridiculous cron syntax.

Jenkins' Modo should be "There's a plugin for that"